# How to Share folders in 14.04 Server with Gnome

Tags: networking, 14.04, server, gnome, samba

I'm working with a new installation of Ubuntu Server 14.04 64 bit.  During installation I picked the Samba Server option and I believe that it is running.  My intention is that an OS X machine will be able to share the top folder in a secondary internal disk (and perhaps a few other folders).  I can ping the server from my mac.  I have a minimal Gnome GUI installed and am adding functionality as needed.

On my 12.04 machine I just right click on a folder and share it.  On the server a right click does not bring up anything to do with sharing so I probably need to install something or edit some file.

How do I enable sharing on a folder?

[edit] I can't detect that Samba is actually running!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test if you have it running by typing `smbstatus`, if it shows any information about connected or not connected clients then it is working, if you get an error, it is not running or installed. Please make sure you also have installed the `libpam-smbpass` package. It is used to sync system users with the samba database for cases like letting users connect to a resource while asking for a password.

```
apt-get install libpam-smbpass
```

If you already have Samba installed with all needed packages then first edit the `smb.conf` file:

```
nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

At the end of the file add the shared resource. In my case I will share a resource called "shareme":

```
[shareme]  
    comment = Server Share Resource  
    path = /path/to/shared/resource  
    browsable = yes  
    guest ok = yes  
    read only = no  
    create mask = 0777
```

Save that by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> which should show an option below about "Do you want to save?" and then exit the editor. Now restart the Samba service:

```
service smbd restart
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/smbd restart
```

The options above are:

**comment** - Shows the comments when browsing through a gui.

**path** - Folder you wish to share

**browsable** - Allows clients to see the shared resource when they use a file explorer (Like explorer on Windows or Nautilus on Ubuntu)
.
**guest ok** - Allow user to connect to the resource without the need for a password.

**read only** - Sets a read-only permission so users don't start going medieval on the shared resource.

**create mask** - When files/folders are created, this will be the permissions they will have set upon creation.. I left it like 777 which would be full to allow anyone to Read, Write or Execute, but if you don't want somebody deleting something, set them to 0755.

This is a general explanation, which does not include a lot of security and user options. If you want, you can also read the [Samba Guide](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/install.html#id2551954) or even jump to the [Ubuntu Samba Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/samba-fileprint-security.html)

Other tips are (Which can be edited in the `smb.conf` file)

- Make sure you are on the same workgroup (First option the samba config file)
- If you start getting weird names on the shared resource, you can try adding the option `mangled names=no` to the Global section in the `smb.conf` file.
- If users can see the shared resource but can not connect to it, even with the settings above, you can add/edit the option `force user = YOUR_USER` in the Global section which forces any resource to think the user connecting is you (Do not do this on a place you don't trust).
- To see all resources on the LAN network, you can use `smbtree` which would look like this:

  ```
  XTREME
      \\CYREX                 cyrex server (Samba, Ubuntu)
          \\CYREX\img             
          \\CYREX\movies          
          \\CYREX\TVSeries        
          \\CYREX\print$          Printer Drivers
          \\CYREX\IPC$            IPC Service (cyrex server (Samba, Ubuntu))

      \\MARY                  mary server (Samba, Ubuntu)
          \\MARY\temas            
          \\MARY\IPC$             IPC Service (mary server (Samba, Ubuntu))
          \\MARY\print$           Printer Drivers
  ```

Lastly, in your question you mention you have a minimal GUI setup with Gnome. If the option to do all the sharing can be done via GUI, then you first need to install the following packages in order to have the option available when right clicking a folder (This may depend if you are using Unity/Files as the GUI or full Gnome/Nautilus as the GUI)

```
apt-get install samba libpam-smbpass samba-dsdb-modules samba-vfs-modules python-samba samba-common-bin samba-common samba-libs nautilus-share libgnomevfs2-extra
```

After restarting, this should be enough to share via GUI and also be able to see shares. Again, in my case, I am testing this with Unity.

Comment: That's a very nice answer layout - I'd like to give a second vote up.  smbstatus didn't provide any information until I made a connection; I didn't expect that.  I've been able to connect with my other Ubuntu machine and my macAir.  I have and will not have a printer available so should I comment out all the printer info in the conf file?

Comment: @NateLockwood there is no harm leaving it there, but sure, you can comment it out to remove the shared resource.

Comment: If I read the answer correctly, this config gives full write permission to any network user without authentication -  no passwords required at all.  So why install libpam-smbpass ?

Comment: @chrislott At the moment it was a requisite. Do not know if it is right now (It may be related to some common libraries). All I know is, without installing it at that moment, it simply did not work. What I actually do afterwards is "sudo pam-auth-update" and remove it from the list.